# Escaping backslashes in a filepath in Java

Tags: java, escaping

I'm trying to move my java program over to windows from linux and am getting all sorts of problems with filepaths.

Latest problem is this:

> public void restoreCorrections(File correctionDir) {
>
> ```
> String filePath = correctionDir.getPath().replaceFirst("Backup" + File.separator + "Corrections" + File.separator, 
>           "Data" + File.separator + "Matches" + File.separator);      System.out.println(filePath);
>
>             ....
> }
> ```

This function is looped through many times with each file from a specific folder (backup\corrections).

I'm given the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape
>   sequence near index 7
>       Backup\Corrections\
>              ^
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)

I've tried adding 
    replaceAll("\\", "\\\\") after getPath() and also replaceAll(File.separator, "\\")

but they both end up with a similar error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near
>   index 1
>       \
>        ^

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the backslashes in the 1st argument to `replaceFirst`:

```
String filePath = correctionDir.getPath().replaceFirst(("Backup" + File.separator + "Corrections" + File.separator).replaceAll("\", "\\"), 
        "Data" + File.separator + "Matches" + File.separator);
```

That argument is a regular expression and is handed to a `Pattern`.

Plus you only want to replace a backslash with a double one if the separator is a backslash. If its a slash (as in Windows) then leave it.

You could also use a non-regex solution:

```
String original = "Backup" + File.separator + "Corrections" + File.separator;
int col = correctionDir.indexOf(original);
String filePath = correctionDir.substring(0, col) + "Data" + File.separator + "Matches" + File.separator + correctionDir.substring(col + original.length());
```

Comment: Are you aware that Windows will be perfectly happy if you use slashes to divide the path parts? There is something about using backslash for the network part of the UNC path though ... maybe you need the "\\Server1" part to have a backslash. I just can't remember the gotcha there. Even then, the rest can use slashes.